# Are these black lines on Canon S100 an LCD fault or something else?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, rear-lcd

My favourite compact has started to show a black area in the LCD. It is not always in the same place, but so far is only in the lower part of the display. The black area does not extend to the edges of the display. So far, I can live with it. But if it gets worse I would like to fix it. See the horizontal line in the lower left of this picture.

[image: LCD defect]

Is this likely a problem with the LCD panel itself or is it something else? If it is the LCD panel there are replacements on ebay and I think I can manage to replace the LCD myself. If the problem is something else, maybe that is possible to fix too?

Comment: Just to be clear - this is not something that shows up on the photograph itself is it?

Comment: It is only visible on the rear LCD not in the actual photo. Today it is only a small blemish but if it grows to a significant part of the LCD I have to do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the lines don't show up on the actual photo's, I would guess that the problem is with the LCD panel itself.  It's possibly a problem with whatever is driving the panel (bad connection maybe?) but I'm guessing it's the panel.  Unfortunately the only sure way to know is to try replacing it and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I have ordered a replacement LCD panel from China yesterday. It was surprisingly inexpensive. Remains to see if it is worth it's price.